# "Chromium wasn't closed correctly"

Tags: chromium

Hy guys,

maybe someone can help me:

If "run apps in background when chromium is closed" = enabled, than I get every time I start chromium the message, that it wasn't closed correctly and if the pages should be srestored.
If "run apps in background when chromium is closed" = disabled, than everything is ok.

So disabeling chromium apps running in the background, even when chromium is closed is the problem. Since I want to have this apps runnings, is there any slutions to not get this message?

Thanks for any help!

Cristian

Comment: It is a bug reported long ago regarding gnome-session. It is not fixed yet.